# How do I firewall my computer so that only traffic go through the VPN?

Tags: vpn, firewall, traffic, configure

I have read "How to configure an Ubuntu server so that all traffic goes through a VPN?" and found it doesn't apply to my case. I am only interested in the client-side of the VPN connection as I am a customer of a commercial VPN service provider.

I wish to route all network traffic through my VPN connection so that when it drops for whatever reason, all internet access is immediately terminated.

How do I go about configuring Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Addition: Would it be better for me to do a very minimal (bare-bones) install of Ubuntu instead of the full suite? My reasons are: (a) a full suite will have more ports to deal with when I set up firewall rules; (b) I only use Ubuntu to surf the internet

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to check your firewall status:

ufw status

than before you turn it on, probably you want to block all ports, all connections, just, everithing, and then to unblock what you need.

ufw default deny

then you add your rules, example:

ufw allow from 111.222.111.222 to 80

but if you have more than one computer, you need for every same line of code for any ip address, or even if it is specific ip range, it should be and 111.222.111.* or even 111.222.*.*

than last: 111.222.111.222 is example ip address, you just type yours instead, and port 80 is also example, change it, with...you know better what port you need.

Comment: @ Dimitris Theodoridis: What is 111.222.111.222? Is it my IP address or the IP address as stated in the config file? My VPN service provider gives me a set of config files in which there are IP addresses with ports like 1194 for UDP transport and 443 for TCP transport. Could you giv me more examples please?

Comment: @ Dimitris Theodoridis: What is 80 in "ufw allow from 111.222.111.222 to 80"? Is 80 the port or the range?

Comment: no no no!!!!! 111.222.111.222 is an example address beacause i dont know your ip address so replace 111.222.111.222 with your ip. port, lok for your vpn port beacause, there is a lot ports for vpn. port 80 is not for that, this is ''open port'' if you open that, everybody can access your network, with permissions declared for files inside. and if you working with 1000 computers on same network, than is better to use asterisks instead of diferent numbers beacause, if you have lot of ip adds like 111.222.111.222 than 111.222.111.223 than 111.222.111.224 than use asterisk what means any number

Comment: or any text. example: if you set 111.222.111.22* that is same as 111.222.111.220 and 111.222.111.221 and.....

Comment: @ Dimitris Theodoridis: My IP address? I don't have a static IP address. I'm on broadband and my ISP assigns me a dynamic IP address.

Comment: what kind of broadband you using, it can also have static ip like my ppp0 mobile broadband, but that is bit complicated to set up, baecause you not do that in /etc/neteork/interfaces you do that in ist own file or even you will need to contact your network provider to ask to asign to you static ip adress beacause you cannot set for all networks static ip with configuration file. so i sugest firs to contact your provider and ask for to asign to you static ip.

Comment: @ Dimitris: It's out of the question. There's no way I'm applying for a static IP broadband. It's far too expensive. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: yes you can work with configuration file for it, but it will not work 100% it depends only on kind of your provider or modem that you have, and i can not give you info about that beacause, i dont have any info about your device, so could be different than my mobile broadband. try to find other solution. you can even try to work with dhpc and command dhclient, but be sure first to make backup of original conf file of network configuration. when you type dhclient that comand renews your ip address try to find more about that on google and how to use it.

Comment: @ Dimitris: You wrote "yes you can work with configuration file for it, but it will not work 100% it depends only on kind of your provider or modem that you have".... Can you explain in greater detail?

Comment: i can explain how it looks in my case but may not be same. i have ppp0 conn. and configurations are in /etc/ppp folder and in lot of others, forexample i have /etc/ppp/peers/provider file, than chap-secrets in /etc/ppp and there is lot of conf files, you should look it if you using mobile broadband as i do, but, DONT CHANGE THAT FILES IF YOU ARE NOT 100% SURE!!!!! and always create first backup of original conf file

Comment: @ Dimitris: Could you upload a sample of your conf. file? I'd like to have a look at it to see how it's done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is my /etc/ppp/ppp.conf file: default:
set log Phase Chat LCP IPCP CCP tun command
 ident user-ppp VERSION (built COMPILATIONDATE)
 set device /dev/cuau0
 set speed 115200
 set dial "ABORT BUSY ABORT NO\\sCARRIER TIMEOUT 5 \
 \"\" AT OK-AT-OK ATE1Q0 OK \\dATDT\\T TIMEOUT 40 CONNECT"
 set timeout 180
 enable dns

 provider:
  set phone "(123) 456 7890"
  set authname foo
  set authkey bar
  set login "TIMEOUT 10 \"\" \"\" gin:--gin: \\U word: \\P col: ppp"
  set timeout 300
  set ifaddr x.x.x.x y.y.y.y 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0
  add default HISADDR sory maybe not look clear but was so long